# How would I use the Factory method if I only have 1 class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Let me explain: I have a **concrete** GUI class for my game:

```java
public class GameGUI
{
    public void addElement(GameGuiElement element) { ... }
}
```

and classes that implement the `GameGuiElement` interface, such as `Button` and `TextBox`.

Until today, I always designed my GUIs like this:

```java
public class SimpleGUI extends GameGUI
{
    public SimpleGUI()
    {
        super("Simple GUI Title");

        addElement(new Button("Click Here"));
    }
}


//somewhere in another class
new SimpleGUI().display(player);
```

But recently I read that it's bad practice to use inheritance *only for* configuration, so I did some research and found the Factory pattern; But how would I apply it if I only have the `GameGUI` class?
I thought of creating this interface:

```java
public interface GameGUIFactory
{
    GameGUI createFirstGUI();
    GameGUI createSecondGUI();
}
```

but my instinct immediately rejects that because configuring even 1 GUI takes a lot of code.. and also doesn't it blatantly violate SRP by being responsible for creating more than 1 GUI?

Comment: The *factory* pattern and the *factory method* pattern are two different design patterns. The reason why you think you want to apply the factory pattern here, is that code reuse? There may be yet other ways to obtain that. I can’t tell from what you write, but my feeling is that you are not *only* using inheritance for configuration but also because your GUIs have some similarity in what you can do with them?

Comment: Code reuse + being able to open 1 GUI from another one without passing its creation dependencies to the first GUI's constructor.
I only used it for configuration, no GUI has any public methods in it.

Comment: @OleV.V. what is the source of "the factory pattern" you refer to? Is there a book or publication that defines it?

Comment: @jaco0646 [One description here: Design Pattern - Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm).

Comment: @OleV.V. that page describes what Head First Design Patterns calls a "Simple Factory". It's a pattern they published as a teaching aid, which in their own words is not intended for production use. I see the same fallacy is repeated in TP's Abstract Factory article, where they double down by combining two Simple Factories. TutorialsPoint is filled with misleading information and nonsense written by unqualified bloggers. It has been confusing developers for many years; but it is so widespread that its misinformation has been repeated many times even on SO, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given information, you could implement a **Factory Method** pattern like it is showed on a diagram below:

[image]

I would like to point out, this design pattern is called a *Factory **Method***, and it is different from a pattern called *Abstract Factory* or a pattern called *Builder*. Here is how you could implement this, based on the diagram above:

```
public interface GUICreator {
    public GameGUI createGUI();
}  

public class SimpleGUICreator implements GUICreator {
    @Override
    public GameGUI createGUI() {
        SimpleGUI simpleGUI = new SimpleGUI();
        simpleGUI.addElements(new Button("Click Here"));
        
        // Here you can add all of the custom elements for your GUI.
        
        return simpleGUI;
    }
} 

public abstract class GameGUI
{
    private String title;
    
    public GameGUI(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    
    public abstract void addElement(GameGuiElement element);
}

public class SimpleGUI extends GameGUI
{
    public SimpleGUI()
    {
        super("Simple GUI Title");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addElement(GameGuiElement element) {
        // Add you implementation here
    }
}
```

However, if you want to implement the default behavior of the `addElement` method for every GUI, you could do that by implementing the method inside the `GameGUI` class.

```
public abstract class GameGUI
{
    public void addElement(GameGuiElement element) {
        // Add you implementation here
    }
}
```

Then, there is no need to override `addElement` method in the child classes if all the GUIs will be using the same method when adding elements.

Please keep in mind that using the *Factory Method* inside a *Creator* class is one way of implementing this pattern. Another way would be using a Parameterized Factory Method, which would allow you to have one class for all the GUI classes instead of having a *Creator* class for every *GUI* class.

---

For your specific case, I think a better fit would be a **Builder** Design Pattern. Here is how you could implement this design pattern using a *Director* class.

[image]

```
// Inside of this interface you will put all of the methods you will
// need in order to build your GUI.
public interface GUIBuilder {
    void buildButtons();
    void buildLabels();
    GameGui getGUI();
}

public SimpleGUIBuilder implements GUIBuilder {
    private GameGui gui;
    
    public SimpleGUIBuilder() {
        gui = new GameGui("Simple GUI Title");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void buildButtons() {
        // Here you will add all of the buttons for you simple GUI.
        // For example:
        gui.addElement(new Button("Click Here"));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void buildLabels() {
        // Here you will add all of the labels for you simple GUI.
    }
    
    @Override
    public GameGui getGUI() {
        return gui;
    }
}

public class Director {
    private GUIBuilder builder;
    
    public Director(GUIBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }
    
    public GameGui getGUI() {
        constructGUI();
        return builder.getGui();
    }
    
    private void constructGUI() {
        // Build elements of your GUI in any order you need.
        builder.buildButtons();
        buildButtons.buildLabels();
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use this in your code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGUIBuilder builder = new SimpleGUIBuilder();
        Director director = new Director(builder);
        
        GameGUI gui = director.getGUI();
    }
}
```

Here you don't violate the **Single Responsibility Principle**. The *Director* class is responsible to know which parts (build methods) should be used in which order, and the *Builder* knows how to implement build methods that are called from the Director.

Comment: I like your designs. What you call *factory method* I would refer to the [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).